# How to calculate the number of walks of length $k$ from one vertex to another?

Tags: graph-theory, adjacency-matrix

There is a theorem on calculating the number of walks of length $k$ from one vertex $v_i$ to another $v_j$, which says that

> Let $G=(V,E)$ be a graph with $V=\{v_1,\dots,v_n\}$ and adjacency
> matrix $A_G=(a_{ij})$. Let $k\in \mathbb{N}$ and let
> $1\le i,j\le n$. The number of walks of length $k$ from $v_i$ to $v_j$
> is equal to the $(i,j)^{th}$ entry of the matrix $A_G^k$.

My first question is that what is $A_G^k$. I don't know what the superscript $k$ means. Other questions are related to the proof of this theorem.

The proof of the theorem is given below:

> Prove by induction on $k$. When $k=1$, the result holds obviously.
> Assume that the result holds for $k$. Let $B=(b_{ij})=A_G^k$.
> Therefore, $A_G^{k+1}=BA=(c_{ij})$ and the $(i,j)^{th}$ entry of
> $A_G^{k+1}$ is $$c_{ij}=\sum_{l=1}^nb_{il}a_{lj}.$$ By the induction
> hypothesis, for all $1\le l\le n$, $b_{il}$ is the number of walks of
> length $k$ between $v_i$ and $v_l$. This value is added to $c_{ij}$ if
> and only if $\{v_l,v_j\}\in E$. Therefore, $c_{ij}$ counts the number
> of walks of length $k+1$ between $v_i$ and $v_j$.

Here comes my next question:
Why $A_G^{k+1}=BA$?
Any help is appreciated!

Comment: The superscript is power: $A^k=\underbrace{A\dots A}_{k \text{ times}}$.

Comment: The notation $A_{G}^{k}$ means the matrix $A_{G}$ to the power $k$. That is, it equals $A_GA_G\cdots A_G$, where we have $k$ copies.

Comment: @AlexanderBurstein,@Marc, so actually, $A_G^{k+1}=A_G^kA_G=BA_G$, and the formula of $c_{ij}$ is the multiplication of matrix?

Comment: @R.C That's what it is.